# Scheduling Flow

Tags: apex, class, visual-workflow, scheduled-apex

I am trying to create a screen flow that is scheduled in Salesforce. From the screen flow I call an Invocable method where I pass my input parameters from my screen flow. From there I call a future method which passes on these values and then finally make my POST callout. My only issue is with scheduling this now. I originally didn't need to send parameters and had the following:

```
global class MyScheduler implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {        
        MyCallouts.makeFuturePostCall();
    }    
}
```

Now I need to send 2 strings from this method (makeFuturePostCall). Or maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way. Any ideas? I just want to be able to schedule this screen flow after I have gotten input from the user.

To be a bit more clear I have a screen that allows a user to enter some parameters. These parameters are passed to an Invocable method. After I have this information I want to be able to schedule this to run without any user interaction. Just keep running with those same 2 parameters.

```
 @InvocableMethod
public static void makeInvocableCall(List<MyInputs> test) {
    futureCall(test[0].param1, test[0].param2);
}
```

Comment: To clarify: what you want to schedule is not the Flow itself, correct? It's this Apex. And you're interested in passing to this Apex some parameters that ultimately come from the Flow? Could you [edit] to clarify and include the `InvocableApex` class?

Comment: @DavidReed I added some more info. I was able to schedule this before from the future method (futureCall with no parameters sent) when I didn't need to send parameters. But now that I do, I don't know how I can schedule this. And yes I want to schedule the apex that gets parameters from the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Schedulable` class can accept parameters that it then passes itself to the future call. As a side note, if you're not building a managed package and intending to expose this class to consumers, it should not be `global`.

Just add a constructor and instance variables, then make the call:

```
public class MyScheduler implements Schedulable {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    public MyScheduler(String param1, String param2) {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {        
        MyCallouts.makeFuturePostCall(param1, param2);
    }    
}
```

Your Invocable Apex should construct an instance of the schedulable class, passing the desired parameters, and then call `System.schedule()`.

This pattern works fine even if your parameters are not primitives, as shown here. They'll just need to be serializable, and I would expect any value coming out of a Flow to be so.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried implementing like you have specified above. I then tried to schedule the apex on the front end via the Schedule Apex button and it said I needed to Select a parameterless Apex class to do that. I am guessing this is why you said I need to use System.schedule(). Do I just call System.schedule('The Name',Expression,MyScheduler) inside makeInvocableCall before my futureCall() ?

Comment: @MarkC5000 Yes, after creating an instance of `MyScheduler` passing in the params you want.